# Induction T/F questions. How to know what the counterexample is.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

Determine whether the statement is true of false. If true, provide a proof. If false provide a counterexample.

for $n \in N, 2n-8 < n^2-8n+17$

I started off like a typical induction proof.

**Base Case: n=1**

$2(1)-8=-6<(1)^2-8(n)+17 = 10$

which holds.

**Inductive Hypothesis**

$2n-8 < n^2-8n+17$

**Inductive Step**

$2(n+1)-8 < (n+1)^2-8(n+1)+17$

$2n-8+2<n^2-6n+10$

**Trying to relate the Inductive Step with the Inductive Hypothesis.**

$(2n-8) + 2 < (n^2-8n+17)+2n-7$

which means I now need to show when

$2<2n-7$

This part clearly doesn't hold for for an n > 5. So, the inductive hypothesis must be false.

However for any n<5, the inductive hypothesis holds, and fails at n=5 (I couldn't find many other counterexample). giving 2<2 (a contradiction)

I have an exam coming up soon, and I'm trying to determine how to find out how to find counterexamples systematically (or as close to systematically as possible) Is there a way to find at which numbers an inductive proof will fail? This one confuses me because the inductive hypothesis fails at 5, but not 6,7,8 or 100. So how could I actually know to try 5? Because here I just got lucky that it was a number that I plugged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be tackled without induction. The inequality $2n-8 < n^2-8n+17$ is equivalent to $0< n^2-10n+25 = (n-5)^2$. This is true for all $n$ except $n=5$.

In general, if you have an inequality of the type $0<an^2+bn+c$, this is true for all $n$ only if the associated second degree equation does not have a positive integer root.